# setup sftp server with special permissions

Tags: ubuntu, sftp

I want to setup SFTP server with special permissions, and most importantly, how to set up the idea

My idea: You access Via secure FTP protocol using Winscp, and you have your own folder, can upload files, download files, read, write, overwrite, delete; and can't go out from your folder another thing, one user can't create a folder too!

Comment: really needs to be [SFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol), can't be [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol) or better [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)?

Comment: That's what chroot is for, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this sounds like a job for a classical FTP server with an [SFTP protocol plugin](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/contrib/mod_sftp.html): ProFTPD can do all  that, and per-directory configuration via a .ftaccess file is possible.

Of course, sshd (like openssh) still would work, if you'd restrict user's ability to execute anything on the server and configure their access rights accordingly, but you'd have to flange on some kind of user database (unless you want to have a UNIX user per SSH user) using PAM (or GSSAPI or whatever).

Comment: Could you more explanation please? 
How can I do this?

Comment: you install proftpd. You enable SFTP in it. How: is explained at the link.

Comment: Thanks! 
How can I create an admin user with full permission to control other users?!

Comment: Read the Proftpd documentation, and if that doesn't answer your question, please open a new question on this site. don't ask new questions in the comments, please.